# How to detect If this class object is duplicated or not

Tags: java, arrays

OK so I have 2 classes that are related to each other without the use of inheritance
class1:

```
public class Userformat {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Userformat(String name, int id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "\nname: "+ name + "\nID: " + id + "\nbooks borrowed: " + booksborrowed + "\n";
    }
}
```

class2 :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class UserList {
    private ArrayList<Userformat> Users;

    public UserList() {
        Users = new ArrayList<Userformat>();
    }

    public void adduser(Userformat userformat) {
        Users.add(userformat);
    }
   
   public boolean checkuserduplicated(String usertitle) {
        boolean pass = false;
        String dieusertitle = usertitle.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < Users.size(); i++){
            Userformat u = Users.get(i);
            if (u.getName().toLowerCase().equals(dieusertitle)) {
                pass = true;
            } else {
                pass = false;
            }
        }
        return pass;
    }
}
```

so basically what happens here is whenever I create a new class object using Userformat() I automatically store it in the UserList()'s array list
what I am struggling with how to stop the .add() method from work when the Userfomat() object has a similar name. TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR this is my main

```
UserList users = new UserList();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your Name: ");
String nameValue = input.nextLine();

Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your ID: ");
int idValue = Integer.parseInt(input2.nextLine());

if (!users.checkuserduplicated(nameValue)) {
           users.adduser(new Userformat(nameValue, idValue));
        }
```

but this doesn't work can someone please help me Thanks

Comment: Implement both the `equals` and `hashCode` methods and then use a `Set` instead of `ArrayList`; for [example](https://roytuts.com/hashset-in-java/); [example](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781789801736/8/ch08lvl1sec49/set-and-uniqueness-in-set); [example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170912/ways-to-ensure-unique-instances-of-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the current implementation of `checkuserduplicated` method is that it returns `false` as soon as it finds a user with a different name than the one being checked. This means that if there are multiple users with same names but the last name is different it will return false.

To fix this, you can update the checkuserduplicated method as follows:

```java
public boolean checkuserduplicated(String usertitle) {
    String dieusertitle = usertitle.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < Users.size(); i++) {
        Userformat u = Users.get(i);
        if (u.getName().toLowerCase().equals(dieusertitle)) {
            return true; // Found a user with the same name, so return true
        }
    }
    return false; // Did not find any user with the same name, so return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly return `true` as soon as a matching name is found. Only return `false` after the end of the loop (after each element of the `List` has been checked). The issue with your current code is that you are only returning the result of the comparison with the **last** element.

```java
public boolean checkuserduplicated(String usertitle) {
    for (User u: Users)
        if (u.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(usertitle))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one good way to implement this is to make your `UserList` extend `ArrayList` and then override the `add()` method.

```
public class UserList extends ArrayList<Userformat> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(Userformat user) {
        if(this.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getName())))
            return false;
        return super.add(user);
    }
}
```

Note that you can check against any other conditions you might want within the `add()` method as well. If it fails any condition, return false and the user won't be added. If it passes all conditions, call `super.add()` to add the user as normal. In addition, this removes the need to declare and manage the list yourself as you inherit all of the methods from `ArrayList`.

If you really want to keep the check method separate, you could implement like this

```
@Override
public boolean add(Userformat user) {
    /* 
     * checkuserduplicated
     * true -> return false, don't add user
     * false -> add user normally (will return true/false according to super implementation)
    */
    return checkuserduplicated(user.getName()) ? false : super.add(user);
}

//I would make this method private as no other class need see it
private boolean checkuserduplicated(String usertitle) {
    return this.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(usertitle));
}
```

Either way, I still recommend extending `ArrayList`.